# Java/Spring Boot: How do I incorporate HTTPS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, https

I am developing a collection of services using Spring Boot to provide the application framework and REST capabilities. I've successfully set up a simple set of services (using just HTTP) and they work beautifully.

Now, I've been asked to have them work with HTTPS. I know very little about "software security methods" and nothing about HTTPS or what is involved in its operation or usage. My research so far indicates that some sort of security certificate(s) need to be defined and that they play a role in the "securing" of the HTTP communications.

I've seen a number of examples and tutorials, and these have helped to some degree with understanding some of the pieces of the puzzle, but the whole picture is still very fuzzy and many pieces are missing. For the most part, it's been a confusing sea of classes and API calls, with little to no explanation as to the "why" of what's being done.

I'm looking for advice on a primer or a *detailed* tutorial on the "correct" way to set up to use HTTPS. It would be very helpful if it explained the various "parts" of the machine, what role they play and when these parts need to be used (and why), or not.

**UPDATE**

I'll try to go into a little more detail.

Based on tutorials I found that discuss "enabling" HTTPS in a Spring Boot application and some of the configuration involved, I put together the following in an attempt to set up and configure HTTPS for my application.

application.yml:

```
...
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:keystore/keystore.p12
    key-store-password: <password>
    key-alias: tomcat
```

**BTW**: having the password in plaintext is not going to cut it. How do we get arond *that*?

SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // I have no idea what I should be specifying here, nor what any of the available methods
    // actually DO.
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // I have no idea what I should be specifying here, nor what any of the available methods
    // actually DO.
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rst").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

}
```

When I attempt to run the application, it's pretty obvious that it's trying to use a security mechanism, but failing because I've haven't done something correctly.

Here is an exception I get from one of the services that's attempting to make a POST call to another:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:8090/rst/missionPlanning/generateRoute": java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
```

OK, found a way to get around the "localhost" problem:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession sslSession) {
    if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
});
```

Now I get a different exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:8090/rst/missionPlanning/generateRoute": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I *did* set up a key using `keytool` before all of this and placed it in `src/main/resources/keystore`.

Another thing that's worth mentioning is that the service making the POST call, is using a different port:

`https://localhost:8090/rst/missionPlanning/generateRoute`

The service being called is configured to use port 8090. How does this fit with HTTPS using port 8443?

Comment: Start with this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-channel-security-https

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please look out this solution which may help you for HTTPS with spring boot
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_enabling_https

Comment: Yes, I already looked at this one. It's a one-pager and really doesn't tell me anything beyond what I'd seen elsewhere.

Comment: you mean you need more details about HTTPS and its internals?

Comment: I guess you could say that. As I mentioned, I know nothing about HTTPS.

Comment: The DZone article was definitely helpful to explain some of the "whats" and "whys" behind HTTPS (and SSL/TLS). What is needed further is some explanation of the security configuration classes/methods (e.g. `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, `HttpSecurity`, et al) used in the Spring security config. The tutorials just provide some sample code, with no explanation as to what/why it's being done that way.